# Retrieving mesh points of a CAD object

Tags: c++, export, mesh, cad, step

I would like to implement functionality that would allow me to export (mesh) points of the surface of a CAD object into a file.

I have had a look at some CAD applications but can't find any that would let me do this directly so I suspect I might need to get the information about mesh points of an object using a CAD application that provides API's.

Please can anyone point me to an application that might help me achieve my aim.

Comment: Do you mean CAD applications you looked at doesn't export to STL or OBJ?

Comment: I want to export mesh points to a text file so that I can write C++ code that will read that file. CAD applications that I have seen export to different formats, if they export to STL or OBJ and I can find a way to get the mesh point in those files, that will be OK too.

Answer (score 1):

How about writing an STL file and then

cat myFile.stl  | grep -i vertex | sort | uniq > myPoints.txt

(also as Windows user you have these commands with Cygwin).

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate this.